# Jquery effect works on only the first id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply a hide effect on all ID's with the same label, but it only works on the first one. I am having the same problem when I tried to add slideToggle too, but figured solving this will solve the others.

**JQUERY**

```
   var allPanels = $('#accordionSlide');

   allPanels.hide();
```

**CSS**

```
   #accordion { 
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
              }
   #accordionBtn { display: block; }

   #accordionSlide { display: block;}
```

**HTML**

```
                <div id="accordion"> 

                    <div id="accordionBtn">
                        <a href="#">Solutions</a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="accordionSlide">
                        <a href="/solutions/wireless-remote-monitoring/index.html">Wireless Remote Monitoring</a>
                    </div>

                    <div id="accordionBtn">
                         <a href="#">Solutions</a>
                     </div>

                    <div id="accordionSlide">
                        <a href="/solutions/wireless-remote-monitoring/index.html">Wireless Remote Monitoring</a>
                    </div> 

                </div>
```

Comment: You cannot have identical `id`s. Change them to classes if you need more than one of the same.

Comment: `id`'s should be unique

Comment: Oh geez ... I knew it might be simple, not THAT simple. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **class** attribute as **id** should be unique for every element. id represents only one element that's why it should be unique. So when you apply selector it only selects the first element that it founds on the page.

do like this:

```
 <div class="accordionSlide">
                        <a href="/solutions/wireless-remote-monitoring/index.html">Wireless Remote Monitoring</a>
                    </div>
```

and jquery:

```
 var allPanels = $('.accordionSlide');

   allPanels.hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

[ID Selector (“#id”)-->Selects a single element with the given id attribute.](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

if you want to apply to all elements then use `class` in place of `id`

```
var allPanels = $('.accordionSlide');

allPanels.hide();
```

html

```
<div class="accordionSlide"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery matches exactly one element when querying for an ID. An array of at most one Element object will be returned by $("#foo").get(). See the jQuery documentation for more information.