# JQuery Val function doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have shown in my code the files saved in the database, it means I used a loop to display them, and in each  element in this loop I put the file name and the input of the hidden type, it has the file path as a value for that input, so I wanted to display the value of each file When I click on it in the alert box, but when i click on any file the alert box shows me the last file path saved in the database.

```
$(document).on("click","#download",function(){
    var file=$("#displayfilename:input").val();
    alert(file);
    console.log(file);
});
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'loaddivdata.php',
        success:function(response){
            $(".postsshow").html(response);
        }
    });
},100);
```

```
<?PHP
//loaddata.php
include("../classses/autoload.php");      
$DB=new connection();
$query="select * from posttext order by id desc";
$result=$DB->read($query);
if($result){
    foreach($result as $posts){
        $output='<div class="flex-column">';
        if($posts['file']!=""){
            $extensionfile=pathinfo($posts['file'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $filename=pathinfo($posts['file'],PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $filepath=$posts['file'];
            if( $extensionfile=='docx' || $extensionfile=="doc" ||
                $extensionfile=="dot"|| $extensionfile=="dotm" || 
                $extensionfile=="dotx" || $extensionfile=="docm")
            {
                $output .='<a href="#" id="download"><img src="../icons/svg/png/142-mot-2.png" style="width: 30px;"/>'.$filename.'.'.$extensionfile.'<input type="hidden" name="displayfilename" id="displayfilename" value="'.$filepath.'"></a>'.'<br>';
            }elseif( $extensionfile=="xls" || $extensionfile=="xlsx" || 
                     $extensionfile=="xlt" || $extensionfile=="xlsm"|| 
                     $extensionfile=="xltx" || $extensionfile=="xltm" || 
                     $extensionfile=="xla"|| $extensionfile=="xlam" )
            {
                $output .='<a href="#" id="download"><img src="../icons/svg/png/140-exceller.png" style="width: 30px;"/>'.$filename.'.'.$extensionfile.'<input type="hidden" name="displayfilename" id="displayfilename" value="'.$filepath.'"></a>'.'<br>';
            }elseif( $extensionfile =='pdf' ){
                $output .='<a href="#" id="download"><img src="../icons/svg/png/134-pdf.png" style="width: 30px;"/>'.$filename.'.'.$extensionfile.'<input type="hidden" name="displayfilename" id="displayfilename" value="'.$filepath.'"></a>'.'<br>';
            }
        }
        $output.='<hr></div>';
        echo $output;            
    }
}else{
    echo "no posts found";
}
?>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: ids should be unique within the dom. If you have more than one post, I don't know what you are expecting...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Code samples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be minimal, complete and representative.

Comment: Also duplicate of "[Jquery effect works on only the first id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23660554/90527)", and likely others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, replace this:

```
var file= $("#displayfilename:input").val();
```

with this

```
var file= $(this).find("input#displayfilename").val();
```

You need to use class '.download' not id '#download', cause ids is a unique selector you cant use the same id in more than one element, it will return only the first element.